# Are _Nullable and _Nonnull useful for anything other than Swift interop?

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-nullability

Does the Objective-C compiler actually warn you if it thinks that you may be passing `nil` to a parameter marked with `_Nonnull`?

Or is it merely a hint to whatever tool converts between Swift and Objective-C to better deal with Swift optionals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On its own, there is warning only in the extremely trivial case: when you pass `nil` to a function accepting `_Nonnull` value.

```
NSObject* _Nonnull test(NSObject* _Nonnull) {
    test(nil);  // warning

    NSObject* _Nullable f = nil;
    test(f); // no warning (passing _Nullable to _Nonnull), only warn in static analysis

    NSObject* _Nonnull g = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    g = nil; // no warning (!) (assigning nil to _Nonnull)

    if (g != nil) {  // no warning (unnecessary '!= nil' comparison)
        test(g);
    }

    return nil; // no warning (returning nil to _Nonnull)
}
```

[image: The code above when compiled in Xcode 7]

(There is a [`-Wnullable-to-nonnull-conversion` flag](http://modocache.io/clang-warn-nullable-to-nonnull-conversion) but it doesn't seem to have any effect to the code above.)

[As documented](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#nonnull), the three attributes will not change the behavior of the code:

> … Note that, unlike the declaration attribute `nonnull`, the presence of `_Nonnull` **does not imply that passing null is undefined behavior**: `fetch` is free to consider null undefined behavior or (perhaps for backward-compatibility reasons) **defensively handle null**.

Beyond the compiler, it will also help the static analyzer, but again clang's static analyzer will only catch the trivial case where it knows for sure you are assigning a `nil` to a `_Nonnull` (i.e. the `test(f)` example above).

Nevertheless, it is still useful to mark a pointer `_Nonnull`/`_Nullable` as

1. Documentation;
2. Allow Swift developers to use your library better;
3. The compiler will emit warnings everywhere if you don't add those annotations

Comment: Should one use `_Nonnull` / `_Nullable` instead of `nonnull` / `nullable`? You seem to prefer the underscore variant, can you please tell why? I personally find `nonnull` and `nullable` easier to read and the following article in the Swift Blog seems to suggest the latter over the former as a nicer alternative: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25

Comment: I agree with the documentation point. Also another quick question: can these attributes be considered as an alternative to `NSParameterAssert(x != nil)` or does one use both of them together?

Comment: @willcodeforf00d `nonnull` cannot be used outside of an Objective-C method declaration. The example I used is a C function.

Comment: @willcodeforf00d You could use both of them together. `_Nonnull` itself does *not* assert that `x` is not nil. You still have to check if `x` is nil or not if you want to be safe.